# C# CodeGeneration variable as type

Tags: c#, code-generation

In an existing application, code is generated to perform a cast, like below: (the types are also generated classes, I provide an example with just `object` and `string`)

```
object o;
string s = (string)o;
```

When o is of type `int`, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown. Therefore, I want to change the code into:

```
object o;
string s = o as string;
```

and check later on whether `string s` is null.

The `System.CodeDom` is used to perform the code generation. The cast is generated using the `CodeCastExpression` Class.

I cannot find a way to generate the `variable as type` way... Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`.
It has methods to check whether it `CanConvertFrom(Type)` and `CanConvertTo(Type)` and has the "universal" ConvertTo Method which accepts an Object in and gives an Object back:

```
public Object ConvertTo(
    Object value,
    Type destinationType
)
```

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try this instead:

```
//For string...
string s = (o == null ? null : o.ToString());
//For int...
int i = (o == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(o));
```

Maybe you can just put an if statement before so the code would read:

```
TheType s = null;

if (o is TheType)
    s = (TheType)o
```

This will only work with non-value-types. See [this post](http://metasharp.net/index.php?title=More_technical_Csharp#Generating_the_.27is.27_operator) for information on how to accomplish the "is" operator.

Comment: Perhaps you could handle other types as described above? I don't think you can use CodeDom to write [variable as Type] - from what I've read this is not supported since the "as" keyword is specific to C#. I'm not sure if that is completely accurate or not.

Comment: As I updated in my original question, the types used are classes that are also generated at runtime... sorry for the ambiguity. Thank you for your answers

Comment: Looks good, but now I am struggling to get the `is` operator correctly in my code... Can you help?

Comment: I haven't done it personally but I've updated the answer with a link to a page with instructions on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Actually, it will result in a bit dirty solution. I've implemented Bazzz's solution. Thanks anyway for your answers!

Comment: Glad you got it working, even if it wasn't my answer. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the 'as' operator cannot be used with a non reference type.

For example:

```
public class ConverterThingy
{
    public T Convert<T>(object o)
        where T : class
    {
        return o as T;
    }

    public T Convert<T>(object o, T destinationObj)
        where T : class
    {
        return o as T;
    }
}
```

This should work for most of it. You can do the as conversion from any object to another reference type.

```
SomeClass x = new ConverterThingy().Convert<SomeClass>(new ExpandoObject());
// x is null
SomeClass x = null;
x = new ConverterThingy().Convert(new ExpandoObject(), x);
// x is null, the type of x is inferred from the parameter
```

Comment: Okay, correct me if I'm wrong, the ConverterThingy is a not-generated helper class?

Comment: Correct. Instead of generating code to do the cast, you can create a helper class to do it better. If you can't access the type directly for the generic call, there is a bit of trickery you can use to get that. I'll update the class to reflect that.

Comment: Honestly, the solution looks a bit over killed to me.. I am trying the suggestion of Josh now. Thanks anyway for your answer!